# SceneKit – NSAttributedString is not shown as SCNText

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, nsattributedstring

Why do these lines of code work:

```
let text = NSString(string: "Test")
(node.geometry as! SCNText).string = text
```

but these ones don't:

```
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Test")
(node.geometry as! SCNText).string = text
```

When using attributed text the `SCNText` simply does not show up. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610914/nsattributedstring-doesnt-work-with-scntext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself. The problem was the font size which is relative to the scene dimensions. In my case the standard font size was way to small.

Sovled!